# using google app script to make spreadsheet into a pdf but getting html

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I created a new spreadsheet with a single sheet holding the subset of data of interest. My script is in the original spreadsheet. In that code I am attempting to create a PDF of the new spreadsheet. The URL that my code generates is:

exportUrl=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M82johI78eIrEf8u9RV_5kPgCDAaSfOcoGVYAyno5gE/?usp=drivesdk/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=LETTER&portrait=true&fitw=true&top_margin=0.75&bottom_margin=0.75&left_margin=0.7&right_margin=0.7&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=false&gridlines=true&fzr=FALSE

The PDF generated in MyDrive does not have the icon of a PDF. If I preview it I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><script nonce="siOEWKm8X/lqnbWRNS06ow">var DOCS_timing={}; DOCS_timing['pls']=new Date().getTime();</script><meta property="og:title" content="tempSs"><meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Google Docs"><meta property="og:url" content="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M82johI78eIrEf8u9RV_5kPgCDAaSfOcoGVYAyno5gE/edit?usp=drivesdk/export?exportFormat%3Dpdf&amp;format=pdf&amp;size=LETTER&amp;portrait=true&amp;fitw=true&amp;top_margin=0.75&amp;bottom_margin=0.75&amp;left_margin=0.7&amp;right_margin=0.7&amp;sheetnames=false&amp;printtitle=false&amp;pagenum=false&amp;gridlines=true&amp;fzr=FALSE&amp;usp=embed_facebook"><meta property="og:description" content="Sheet1

Abdalla,WilliamAbdalla
Aden,VickieAden
Allen,VeronicaAllen
etc.
```

When I download it and it has a file extension of html. If I open it the data is there but there is a lot of header stuff which makes no sense. If I change the file extension to pdf I get Error: Failed to load pdf

My code:

```
/**
 * based on https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/
 */
function exportAsPDF() {
 fileName = “tempSs”;
 var ssId = getMostRecentFile(fileName);
 var ssBaseUrl = getMostRecentFile(fileName);
 var blob = _getAsBlob(ssBaseUrl);
 _exportBlob(blob, fileName);
}

/**
 * Assume multiple spreadsheets with same name
 * only want to use the most recent
 */
function getMostRecentFile(fileName) {
 ssIt = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
 var createDate, prevCreateDate, tempSsId;
  
 var result = [];
 while (ssIt.hasNext()) {
  var file = ssIt.next();
  result.push([file.getDateCreated(),file.getId(), file.getUrl()]);
 } 
 var dTime = result.sort()[0][0];
 var tempSsId = result.sort()[0][1];
 var ssBaseUrl = result.sort()[0][2];
// Logger.log(“tempSsId: ” + tempSsId + ” dTime: ” + dTime);

 return ssBaseUrl;
}

function _getAsBlob(ssUrlBase) {

// Logger.log(“ssUrlBase before remove edit: ” + ssUrlBase );
 var ssUrlBase = ssUrlBase.replace(/edit?/,”);
 Logger.log(“ssUrlBase: ” + ssUrlBase );

 var exportUrl = ssUrlBase
   + ‘/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf’
   + ‘&size=LETTER’
   + ‘&portrait=true’
   + ‘&fitw=true’    
   + ‘&top_margin=0.75’        
   + ‘&bottom_margin=0.75’      
   + ‘&left_margin=0.7’       
   + ‘&right_margin=0.7’      
   + ‘&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false’
   + ‘&pagenum=false’
   + ‘&gridlines=true’
   + ‘&fzr=FALSE’;
    
 Logger.log(‘exportUrl=’ + exportUrl);
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
  headers: { 
   Authorization: ‘Bearer ‘ + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
  },
 })
  
 return response.getBlob();
}
```

Why am I not getting a valid PDF in MyDrive or when downloaded? My thanks to everyone. I would not have got this far without constant use of the fine answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the URL of `exportUrl=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M82johI78eIrEf8u9RV_5kPgCDAaSfOcoGVYAyno5gE/?usp=drivesdk/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=LETTER&portrait=true&fitw=true&top_margin=0.75&bottom_margin=0.75&left_margin=0.7&right_margin=0.7&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=false&gridlines=true&fzr=FALSE`. I notice that the modification point.

  - I think that `/?usp=drivesdk/export?` is the modification point. Please modify to `/export?`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- And, in your script, the fonts of the double quotations and the single quotations are required to be modified. In your script, please modify `“` and `”` to `"`, and `‘` and `’` to `'`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function exportAsPDF() {
  fileName = "tempSs";
//   var ssId = getMostRecentFile(fileName); // It seems that this variable is not used in your script.
   var ssBaseUrl = getMostRecentFile(fileName);
   var blob = _getAsBlob(ssBaseUrl);
   _exportBlob(blob, fileName);
}

function getMostRecentFile(fileName) {
  ssIt = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var createDate, prevCreateDate, tempSsId;
  var result = [];
  while (ssIt.hasNext()) {
    var file = ssIt.next();
    result.push([file.getDateCreated(),file.getId(), file.getUrl()]);
  } 
  var dTime = result.sort()[0][0];
  var tempSsId = result.sort()[0][1];
  var ssBaseUrl = result.sort()[0][2];
  return ssBaseUrl;
}

function _getAsBlob(ssUrlBase) {
  var ssUrlBase = ssUrlBase.replace(/\/edit.+/,"");  // Modified
  var exportUrl = ssUrlBase
  + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&size=LETTER'
  + '&portrait=true'
  + '&fitw=true'
  + '&top_margin=0.75'
  + '&bottom_margin=0.75'
  + '&left_margin=0.7'
  + '&right_margin=0.7'
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
  + '&pagenum=false'
  + '&gridlines=true'
  + '&fzr=FALSE';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
  return response.getBlob();
}
```

#### Note:

- From your question, I couldn't understand about `_exportBlob(blob, fileName);`. So it supposes that `_exportBlob(blob, fileName);` works.

Comment: changed a double quotes to single.   Added missing code.

Comment: @aNewb Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from `changed a double quotes to single. Added missing code.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, if you can do, please add your current script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @aNewb Now I noticed that you are trying to edit my answer. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the issue of my answer for your question? By this, I would like to think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I am creating the code in the tool |  script editor so I do not think I have odd quotes. I did change all the " to '. I am using a standard PC keyboard and no word processor so should not have **“ and ”**  or ** ‘ and ’** .  The reged you suggested did not remove edit or usp  - exportUrl=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xoctSVVyN--1HPjcbHwxYFW1ft1NPS41RVJmhG0ztTE/edit?usp=drivesdk/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size . . . is 'worse' than before. The file is definitely not a */edit?usp=drivesdk/**. The PDF as served up by the _exportBlob(blob, fileName) code .

Comment: @aNewb Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you add your current script for replicating your current issue to your question? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because in my environment, I can confirm that the modified script worked. I apologize for this. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @aNewb When I tested your script, an error occurred at the lines using `“`, `”`, `‘` and `’`. So I proposed to modify them. From `I am creating the code in the tool | script editor so I do not think I have odd quotes.`, when you can use the script, I think that it's no problem. Because I think that the main reason of your issue is `?usp=drivesdk/export?` of the URL. So I proposed to modify from `var ssUrlBase = ssUrlBase.replace(/edit?/,”);` to `var ssUrlBase = ssUrlBase.replace(/\/edit.+/,"");`. But from `'worse' than before.`, I would like to confirm your current script for replicating it.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike - when I put that regedit in the result was a good PDF. I wonder what a USP is and why it was in there? Does not matter. It works now!